# ionic-4 Text-wrap on ion-select-option

Tags: css, ionic4, shadow-dom

**HTML**

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Popover</ion-label>
    <ion-select [interfaceOptions]="customPopoverOptions" interface="popover" placeholder="Select One">
      <ion-select-option value="brown" text-wrap>Brownasdfasdfasdfasdfadfadsfasdfadfasdfafdsadfaf</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="blonde">Blonde</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="black">Black</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="red">Red</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
```

[image]

**SASS:**

```
ion-select-option{
   ion-label{
     white-space: normal !important;
   }
}
```

> I'm not able to override the existing `white-space: nowrap`
>
> I would like to know how to override the shadow-dom css

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As there's no attribute for this web-component it does make this a little difficult and messy

global.scss:

```
.item.sc-ion-label-md-h, .item .sc-ion-label-md-h{
     white-space: normal !important;
}

//or just 

 .sc-ion-label-md-h{
     white-space: normal !important;
}
```

This overrules the component styling classes.

[image]

Comment: I don't have a global.css in my ionic 4 project

Comment: You should not have a global.css.  You should have a global.scss.  It is in the /src/global.scss folder.  Check this for more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60212805/missing-app-scss-in-ionic-tabbed-project-using-ionic-4/60212821

Comment: Thank you! Your answer taught me some new concepts!
I added the code in my app.scss and it worked.

Comment: If anyone here is using ionic 5+ with tailwind you can add this SCSS to your tailwind.scss file.

Answer (score 14):

On Ionic 5, the only thing that worked for me was:

```
.alert-radio-label.sc-ion-alert-md {
  white-space: normal !important;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In your global.scss add this:

```
.alert-radio-label.sc-ion-alert-md {
   white-space: pre-line !important;
}

.alert-radio-label.sc-ion-alert-ios {
    white-space: pre-line !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit assets/global.scss:

```css
/* <ion-select multiple="true" ... */
.alert-checkbox-label.sc-ion-alert-md,
.alert-checkbox-label.sc-ion-alert-ios {
  white-space: normal !important;
}

/* <ion-select multiple="false" ... */
.alert-radio-label.sc-ion-alert-md,
.alert-radio-label.sc-ion-alert-ios {
  white-space: normal !important;
}
```

Tested in `"@ionic/angular": "6.1.2"`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Ionic V5.4.15:

```
.alert-checkbox-label.sc-ion-alert-ios{
    white-space: pre-line !important;
    padding-top: 4px;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added this to my `global.scss` file and it seems to work well.

```
.alert-radio-button {
  height: auto !important;
}

.alert-radio-label {
  white-space: normal !important;
}
```

I only tested it in an iOS emulator, not on a real iOS devices or on Android devices or emulators.

Answer (score 0):

For ionic 5

```css
.alert-checkbox-label{
  white-space: normal !important;
}

.alert-tappable.sc-ion-alert-md {
  height: initial !important;
  contain: initial !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in your global.scss

```
.alert-tappable.alert-radio {
 height: auto;
 contain: content; 
}

.alert-radio-label.sc-ion-alert-md, .alert-radio-label.sc-ion-alert-ios {
  white-space: normal; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to each select-option & then target that from global.scss.

### HTML

- I'll add a `text-wrap` class to every ion-select-option:

  ```
   <ion-select
    placeholder="select your option"
    interface="popover"
    (ionChange)="handleChange($event)">
    <ion-select-option class="text-wrap" *ngFor="let entry of this.dropDownList" value="{{entry}}">{{entry}}</ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
  ```

### global.scss

Here I am targeting that `text-wrap` class:

```
   ion-popover ion-select-popover {
     ion-item.text-wrap ion-label {
        white-space: normal !important;
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Ionic Version 7**

In order to do this properly you need to open your dev tools and look at the class for options in a select and find a class that relates only to select and write a global or a component scope css to target the specified class and override some of the properties and/or add new ones. Sometimes you dont have direct class to target the specific element so you need to find a unique tag name and select the target using css selectors.

**Note:** I am using `interface="action-sheet"` as the property for select, The solution might differ for other type of `interfaces`

```
/* This part is for the place holder when the select is not open */
ion-select::part(placeholder),
ion-select::part(text) {
    white-space: normal !important;
}

/* This part is for option text when you open the select */
.select-interface-option span {
    white-space: normal !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use builtin [CSS Utilities](https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities#text-modification) class `.ion-text-wrap`:

```html
<ion-label class="ion-text-wrap">Very long label...</ion-label>
```

Comment: This is not applicable to ion-select-option

Comment: Yes you are right. But this can be applied to the checkbox label. 
Also ion-select label has a height limit of 44px, only fit two lines.