# Missing app.scss in ionic tabbed project using ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I created an ionic 4 tabbed project. It did not create the file /src/app/app.scss. I tried manually creating the file but it does not integrate into the project. Has the file been replaced with a different file name in ionic 4? Thank you.

**Update #1**

I found some information that the file should be called global.scss. I renamed the file that I had created from app.scss to global.scss. That did not help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing app.scss in ionic tab project using ionic 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60212118/missing-app-scss-in-ionic-tab-project-using-ionic-4)

Comment: No it does not.  Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem!  First of all **app.scss** is now called **global.scss** in ionic 4. Also, the file **global.scss** already existed in another folder:

```
/src/global.scss
```

So I deleted the file I had created:

```
/src/app/global.scss
```

Another tip: If you want to know what global style file you are using, open the file **angular.json** and view the section:

```
"styles": [
              {
                "input": "src/theme/variables.scss"
              },
              {
                "input": "src/global.scss"
              }
            ]
```